# RabbitMQ Node statistics not available in cluster node

Tags: rabbitmq, centos, devops, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I have installed RabbitMQ in centos in node1(master) and node2(slave) is 3.8.2 Erlang 22.2 lower version and another node 3 (slave) is RabbitMQ 3.9.8 Erlang 24.1,when i clustered node1 and node 2 is shows fine and but node 3 is i can able to join the cluster when i see the RabbitMQ Overview Node statistics not available in the third node.

when check the cluster status all three are able to see.

1. enabled rabbitmq-plugins rabbitmq_management

node1 and node 2 when i check the management below screen shot.
[image]

when i check the node 3

[image]

Comment: Hi Raja Madhu, Were you able to figure the root cause out?

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter the same issue and after running following command on the same server which appears yellow (**rabbitmq node statistics not available**) in admin UI and resolve the issue.

**$ rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management**

Answer (score 0):

It might be the 100% disk usage on some of the nodes, but there are other possibilities that should be considered. Check the usage of the `/opt/rabbitmq` path

```sh
du -sch /opt/rabbitmq/*
```

I resolved the error from: https://devcoops.com/resolve-rabbitmq-node-statistics-not-available/
It's well explained with steps, and they are considering more cases regarding Node statistics not available error

Comment: i verified systemctl status rabbitmq-server status is active and and its new instance all nodes and net_ticktime is 60,i tried no luck.